# postgres uses a database password or a user password

Tags: postgresql, passwords, pg-hba.conf

I imported a postgres database in my local postgres server. 
I had to connect to the database (to allows django to retrive data) using the file called setup.local.

There is required to specify: `DB_HOST=localhost`, `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`.

DB_HOST is `localhost` without any doubt.  The DB_name is the one I choose importing (`psql imported_db < downloaded_DB`)

DB_USER is my_name (or I can change the owner `ALTER DATABASE imported_db OWNER TO other_name`).

The wire thing, for me, is that I have to use the user (either the my_name or other_name) password and not the database password (even if the variable name is DB_PASSWORD).

So the question: 
does a psql database have a password or just the roles/users have ones and use them to access the database?

Andrea

Comment: There are no database passwords. For users only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passwords are set for `USER` and `ROLE` only. A user may access multiple databases, according to the GRANTs for the ROLE.

See also:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-priv.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/client-authentication.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/user-manag.html

Answer (score 0):

`DB_HOST=localhost` is a key here. Look into the `pg_hba.conf` you will find `ident` against `localhost` connections most probably.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT

> When ident is specified for a local (non-TCP/IP) connection, peer
>   authentication (see Section 20.3.6) will be used instead.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER

> The peer authentication method works by obtaining the client's
>   operating system user name from the kernel and using it as the allowed
>   database user name (with optional user name mapping). This method is
>   only supported on local connections.